# UDF that outputs an array of unknown length

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I am trying to make a function that takes in 3 values, and outputs that many of three different numbers in array format (in this case 1,2,4). For example: EntryArray(1,3,2) would output vertically: 1,2,2,2,4,4.

The way I've been doing it(below) gives me an error and it says "Constant expression required" towards the "entry(**Length**, 0)". Meaning I am required to specify the size of the array beforehand:

```
Function EntryArray(One As Integer, Two As Integer, Four As Integer) As Integer()

Dim Length As Integer
Length = One + Two + Four

Dim entry(**Length**, 0) As Integer

For i = 0 To Length
If i <= One Then entry(i, 0) = 1
If i > One And i <= Two Then entry(i, 0) = 2
If i > Two Then entry(i, 0) = 4
Next i

EntryArray = entry

End Function
```

Comment: How do I do that? I'm extremely new to VBA

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were asking about VB.NET

Comment: You should `Dim` first without any size, then `ReDim`.